# How to store null for empty date field in database in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, date, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a form where there are so many fields. In that, there are checkboxes. If the user checked yes then other fields will be visible and if checked no then that field will be disabled.
In my case, how to handle date parameters if it is empty or null in the controller. Because it is throwing me an exception of non-parseable date for an empty string. I want to store something else (it can be null or NA) for an empty date string in DB.

**Below is my API Controller:**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.addDriverinfo, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<?> addDriverinfo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam(required=false) String dob, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String socialsecurityno, 
    @RequestParam(required=false) String applicationdate, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String appliedposition, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String companyname, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String companyaddress, 
    @RequestParam(required=false) String availabilitydate, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String workstatus, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String isworkedbefore, @RequestParam(required=false) String oldworkdatefrom, 
    @RequestParam(required=false) String oldworkdateto, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String previousdesignation, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String leavingreason, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String licensestate, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String drivinglicense, @RequestParam(required=false) String expirydate, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String isDeniedlicense, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String deniedlicensereason, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String isSuspended, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String suspendreason, 
    @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String isDisqualified, @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="NA") String disqualifyreason) {
  logger.info("Add driver basic details function is called ");
  CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
  try {
    UserBasicDetail userdetail = null;
    User loginuser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    
    UserBasicDetail user = userDetailDao.findByPhone(phone);
    if(user == null) {
      user = new UserBasicDetail();
      Integer deniedlicense = Integer.parseInt(isDeniedlicense);
      user.setIsDeniedlicense(deniedlicense);
      Integer disqualified = Integer.parseInt(isDisqualified);
      user.setIsDisqualified(disqualified);
      Integer suspended = Integer.parseInt(isSuspended);
      user.setIsSuspended(suspended);
      user.setCreatedby(loginuser);
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Date d1 = sdf.parse(applicationdate);
      user.setApplicationdate(d1);
      Date d2 = sdf.parse(expirydate);
      user.setExpirydate(d2);
      Date d3 = sdf.parse(availabilitydate);
      user.setAvailabilitydate(d3);
      Date d4 = sdf.parse(oldworkdatefrom);
      Date d5 = sdf.parse(oldworkdateto);
      user.setOldworkdatefrom(d4);
      user.setOldworkdateto(d5);
      user.setAppliedposition(appliedposition);
      user.setCompanyaddress(companyaddress);
      user.setCompanyname(companyname);
      user.setDeniedlicensereason(deniedlicensereason);
      user.setDisqualifyreason(disqualifyreason);
      user.setDrivinglicense(drivinglicense);
      user.setLeavingreason(leavingreason);
      user.setLicensestate(licensestate);
      user.setPreviousdesignation(previousdesignation);
      Integer status = Integer.parseInt(workstatus);
      user.setWorkstatus(status);
      user.setSocialsecurityno(socialsecurityno);
      user.setSuspendreason(suspendreason);
      Integer workedbefore = Integer.parseInt(isworkedbefore);
      user.setIsworkedbefore(workedbefore);
      Date d6 = sdf.parse(dob);
      user.setDob(d6);
      userdetail = userDetailDao.save(user);
      
      if (userdetail != null) {
        CustomResponse.setResponse(userdetail);
        CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
        CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
        CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
      }
    }
    
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
    CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
    CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
    CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at wing.ak.mydriver.handler.AkApiController.addDriverinfo(AkApiController.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at wing.ak.mydriver.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
```

**I want to get a null value when this field is empty so it should be done?**

Comment: Which datatype select for `date` column in your database

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
 private Date availabilitydate;